# Json_encode returns json cells as string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got a [database structure like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldNdq.png)
I'm willing to get row as a json object for Json.net.

My php code is this

```
$check_query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users where name = '$name' and password = '$pass'");
$rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_query)) {
       $rows[] = $r;
    }
if(count($rows) > 0) {
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
}
```

I'm getting json as this.

```
{"unique_id":"pcg9sy26","name":"w","password":"w","mail":"alpsavrum@gmail.com","age":18,"locale":"Turkey","city":"Istanbul","subscriptions":"[\"electronics\", \"vacations\"]","history":null,"token":"12562f39b990da0433d7be71992ed634"}
```

As you can see, subscriptions value is string. I need it to be array as it seems.

```
{"unique_id":"pcg9sy26","name":"w","password":"w","mail":"alpsavrum@gmail.com","age":18,"locale":"Turkey","city":"Istanbul","subscriptions":[\"electronics\", \"vacations\"],"history":null,"token":"12562f39b990da0433d7be71992ed634"}
```

Is there any way to achieve this. ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The first one is valid JSON. The second one is junk. If you want a JSON array you'll need to remove those backslashes.

Comment: That's not the problem  man, Json.net handles backslash thing. I need to get rid of theese quotation marks.

Comment: If it handles it that's a bug. [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com) gives it the hard thumbs down on the second, bugged out version. How are you getting this string? Is it something you're composing or something you're receiving?

Comment: nothing is wrong with my json parser tadman, i just need to get that array as array not string.

Comment: Can you answer the question: Do you *construct* this JSON or do you *receive* it? The array value is double encoded. You need to JSON decode it separately to get the array back.

Comment: I'm constructing it, how can i prevent that double encode

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you encoded this in the first place? It helps us if we can see what you've done to get that result, especially if we can use that code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're retrieving that data is giving you the JSON value *as a string*. Storing it as JSON in the database is a good idea if it's actually JSON data, but the `mysqli` driver will not automatically de-serialize it for you. If you want that sort of behaviour you'll need to use an ORM.

When you're having trouble with double encoding, check with `var_dump` to see what you're actually working with. That would reveal the `subscriptions` key contains a JSON string, not an array as expected.

What you'll have to do is manually de-serialize it prior to JSON encoding:

```
if (isset($r['subscriptions'])) {
  $r['subscriptions'] = json_decode($r['subscriptions']);
}

$rows[] = $r;
```

You will need to do this for any and all JSON encoded fields your results might have.

This way you're JSON encoding a proper PHP data structure and not one that's part PHP and part JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Try json decode function in whatever language you are reading it.
Decode the JSON response and then print it

Comment: when i print it prints out as i said. problem is i can't print json array as array when i encode it in php.

Comment: Have you  done JSON decode?. And is subscription is send in array from response end

Comment: Json encode encodes the data into string ..hence you are getting is JSON string

Comment: I don't need to decode anything, I need to encode an sql query as json to communicate cross-device. Thus I'm encoding a row of query. 

I've got a column that holds subscriptions as a json value (I'll use it only for array) but when i encode all query, that column returns as string. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the raw data which you are encoding.. so that I can help u better

Comment: Shashikant, I'm trying to encode a mysqlo query which holds a json cell. But encoding gives me string instead of an array like;

"right_json" : ["array","here"]

but instead it's giving me;

"bad_json" : "["array","here"]"

hope it's clear.

Comment: Yes because it treats the value as string and hence u are getting that . You can check out his example :        
 <?php
$s=array('t'=>'test','y'=>array('1','2'));
$js=json_encode($s);
echo($js); 
print_r(json_decode($js));

Comment: You were right actually, I didn't realized that it was double encoded. Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: your welcome sir, you can mark my solution upvote if found me helpful